# Removing Unwanted Blank Page after TOC in a Modified Document Class

Tags: templates, document-classes, thesis, blank-page

I am using a modified document class for writing a thesis. There is an unwanted blank page coming immediately after TOC and before the Introduction chapter, which spoils the pagination in my document also. How can I handle this please?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[openany, showabstract,showacknowledgments]{thesis}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in] {geometry}


\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\title{My Thesis}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}

\tableofcontents

%here exists the unwanted page as number 1
\chapter{Introduction/1.1}

\end{document}
```

ّI believe the problem in the .cls file is in this part:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\thispagestyle{plain}
\global\@topnum\z@
\@afterindentfalse
 \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

Comment: We have no idea what your class does to your document. Usually a `\chapter` starts on a right hand page, with, if necessary, a blank page before it.

Comment: Should I add the class code?

Comment: @Ali According to the fragment code you show in the `.cls` file, if you specify `openany` option, it shouldn't be a blank page after table of contents. Unless the `.cls` file redefine the `\clearpage` command somehow.

Comment: I tried to comment the "if" thing and then begin every new chapter with \newpage and it worked. But at the end of the compiled document there were a number of blank pages when I did this.

Comment: It would be good to post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) we can actually compile to replicate the issue; which means we'll need access to the document class file, and minimal version of your file that has the same problem.

Comment: Nice. I would do so

Comment: I think that there are many `thesis` class files. Which are you using? It seems that it wants to have a specific number of pages, perhaps grouped as multiples four or eight, and introduces a number of blank page at the end to make the numbers up. Perhaps the class you are using gives the results that your thesis supervisors are expecting and they could get upset if you change it.